# How do I add a color of the gradient to each cell (or row) of a TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a color of a specific gradient to each cell of a table view. So far all I've managed to do, is set the gradient for each of the cells. I've found another post which is close to mine but only sets two colors for alternating rows by determining the number of rows and attributing a certain color depending on whether the row number is pair or not. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340722/how-can-i-set-two-colors-to-alternative-row-in-two-different-sections-in-uitable).
Here is the code I am using for the gradient of each cell; how do i attribute each color of the gradient to a cell instead?

```
    CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    grad.frame = cell.bounds;

    grad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:252/255.f green:135/255.f blue:208/255.f alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:253/255.f green:91/255.f  blue:105/255.f alpha:1] CGColor], nil];

    [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478975/how-to-set-multiple-gradient-colour-in-uitableviewcell-using-cagradientlayer-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, You can add a switch statement with as many cases as you need to fit the number of cells you have. Here is the code:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:252/255.f green:135/255.f blue:208/255.f alpha:1] CGColor]
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:253/255.f green:91/255.f  blue:105/255.f alpha:1] CGColor]
        break;
    default:
        cell.backgroundColor = //aother GCColor of your choice
        break;
}
```

and so on. For your first cell, you will use case 0, for the second cell use case 1, and so on. You can add as many cases as you need to match the number of cells you have. And make sure you use `default:` for the last cell.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, but this isn't exactly what I was looking for; using the above method I'd have to go through the colors myself all the way to the last cell :( Idk if I expressed myself well in my question, but I was looking for a gradient to be applied to the cells as 'one body' per se, with each cell having a color of the linear gradient.

Comment: So, can't you try adding a gradient background and make the tableView transparent?

Comment: I tried that but the whole simulator lags when scrolling through the items. Idk if this is because I am using Xcode 6 or it just does that in general

Comment: Did you try it on a real device?

Comment: Yes and it works perfectly! Thank you very much @Steve Sahayadarlin !

Comment: I can't uproot - my rep isn't high enough

Comment: That's ok well glad I could help

Comment: Do you have solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478975/how-to-set-multiple-gradient-colour-in-uitableviewcell-using-cagradientlayer-in